# working with dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on an application where I need to find the difference between the date the user enters into a form and the current date. Right now with the code I have, when I type in the current date it always shows a difference of 2. I would appreciate any advice on how I could straighten this out.

```
function compareDates(dueDate) {  //dueDate is the value from the form
var cdate = new Date();
var cdateparse = Date.parse(cdate);
var dueDateparse = Date.parse(dueDate);
var diff = dueDateparse - cdateparse;
var daysCal = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
var days = Math.floor(daysCal);
console.log(days);  //keeps returning -2 when I enter the current date into the form
try {
 if(diff < 0) {
 mymessage = "this task is overdue by" + " " + -days + " " + "days"; //shows 2 
  throw new Error("you are overdue");
  }
  }
 catch(ex) {
 alert(ex.message);
 return;
 }
if(diff > 0) {
console.log("the difference is greater than 0");
mymessage = "you have" + " " + days + " " + "more days";
}
}
```

Comment: and when I try a date that is two days into the future it says that "i have 0 more days"

Comment: Can you give an example string of the date you enter into the form?

Comment: Give us example input for dueDate please

Comment: this is what I've been using 2013-03-18

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to take care of it for you, it has a build in [difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) API and would be used like so:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't. I'm doing this for an assignment and must use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to round the daysCal value before applying Math.floor().

```
.....

var days = Math.floor(Math.round(daysCal));
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

First off to get the current date you should use `Date.now()` instead of `+new Date`. It's faster in supporting browsers, and [this polyfill for IE<9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Compatibility) is easy as pie:

```
Date.now = Date.now || function() {
    return +new Date;
};
```

You don't even need to do this if you use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) though:

```
moment(someDate).fromNow()
```

[`.fromNow()` on momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

---

I would recommend using moment.js as [@Slace recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15490360/552067). I'm using moment.js in a web app I'm making. Their relative date methods return easy-to-read formats like "a few seconds ago", "four years ago", etc. Super simple!